# jquery chosen select field is displayed wrong

Tags: css, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to use jquery-chosen plugin on simple select code

```
<select class="chosen-select">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="c">c</option>
</select>
```

Turn it on in js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!", allow_single_deselect: true})
});
```

And my select field looks different from fields on jquery-chosen site examples:
[image]

What am i doing wrong? Not adding any css to this field?

Comment: that does smell like a css issue. are you sure the chosen plugin css is being linked for the page?

Comment: yes, i also linked `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/chosen.css"></script>`

Comment: there's your issue maybe. that's a script reference not a css link.

Comment: how css should be linked?

Comment: answered, see if that does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are referencing the css file as a script, it needs to be a css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path to file]chosen.css" />
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="[path to file]chosen.min.css" />
```

point is to reference where the css or min.css file is. based on your comment it might be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/chosen.css" />
```